# restore python3.6 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

my ubuntu 18.04 had a default python3 to python3.5. I wanted to use python3.6, so I removed all instances of python3.5.

unfortunately, then I found out I don't have python3.6 in the os, only in my conda env. Now /usr/bin/python3 doesn't point to anything, and I can't even run lsb_release -a

There are no instructions I can find for installing python3.6 on ubuntu 18.04, they all say it should come by default. anyone knows how I can install python3.6 on it?

Comment: I guess `sudo apt-get install python3` should do the trick? If you want a specific version, you can also put it there

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://askubuntu.com/a/682875/883598

Comment: I managed to get python3.5 back with sudo apt-get install python3.5. Then using sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa, sudo apt-get install python3.6 also worked